# How to combine multiple ConditionalExpressions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Let's say I want to solve

```
Solve[Sin[a] == 0, a]
(* {{a -> 2 π C[1] if C[1] ∈ ℤ } , {a -> π + 2 π C[1] if C[1] ∈ ℤ }} *)
```

That is `a` can have values in the set1 = `..., -2 π, 0, 2 π, 4 π, ...` and in the set2 = `..., -1 π, π, 3 π, 5 π, ...`
Now, set1 and set2 can be combined into set3 = `..., -1 π, 0, π, 2 π, ...` that is `a -> π C[1] if C[1] ∈ ℤ`.

How can I join the two sets of solutions, set1 and set2, and get Mathematica to give me the expression

```
(* a -> π C[1] if C[1] ∈ ℤ *)
```

Comment: Closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212501/reducesinx-0-x-splitting-odd-and-even-multiples-of-pi

Comment: @LukasLang yes, the two questions point to the same problem. In my question  I use Mathematica 13 and `Solve` while the other question probably uses an old version of Mathematica with `Reduce`. Unfortunately, currently there are no replies